# Docker Desktop requires a newer WSL kernel version

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed docker on win 11 and after running I got this error :
Docker Desktop requires a newer WSL kernel version.

I checked WSL version that was 1.1.3.0 which is compatible with docker requirement.
so I don't know what the problem is !

Installing Docker on win 11

Answer (score 12):

1. Access the Control Panel on your Windows computer.
2. Navigate to the "Programs" section and proceed to "Turn Windows features on or off."
3. Mark the checkboxes corresponding to `Windows Subsystem For Linux`, `Windows Hypervisor Platform` and `Virtual Machine Platform`. After that, click the "OK" button.
4. Launch PowerShell with Administrator privileges. Enter the following command: `dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux /all /norestart`, and then hit Enter. This action will enable WSL 1.
5. Install WSL 2 update by running either `wsl.exe --install` or `wsl.exe --update`.
   Execute the command: `wsl --set-default-version 2`, and press Enter to designate WSL 2 as the default version.
   To ensure the modifications take effect, restart your computer.

Comment: Thank you! Just a comment, first tried `wsl.exe --install` option and Docker still prompted the same error. Then tried the `wsl.exe --update` option and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can also open the cmd and type: `wsl --update`

If the problem persists, the following link may be helpful:
[How to update Wsl kernel on win 11](https://pureinfotech.com/update-wsl-kernel-windows-11/)